# calculate value by the day over multiple years with a date column in r

Tags: r

Is there a way to calculate max, mean, and average by the day with a date column in r

Example input

```
   Date         Value
   1999/01/01    1.2
   1999/01/02    2
   2000/01/01    1
   2000/01/02    3
   2001/01/01    2
   2001/01/02    3
```

Example Output

```
Day    Min    Max  Mean
01/01  1      2    1.4
01/02  2      3    2.67
```

Answer (score 2):

With `summary` + `tapply`:

```r
with(df, tapply(Value, substr(Date, 6, 10), summary))
```

output

```r
$`01/01`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0     1.1     1.2     1.4     1.6     2.0 

$`01/02`
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.000   2.500   3.000   2.667   3.000   3.000
```

---

or with more flexibility, you can build your own function:

```r
with(df1, tapply(Value, substr(Date, 6, 10), 
                 \(x) c(min = min(x), mean = mean(x), max = max(x))))
```

```r
$`01/01`
 min mean  max 
 1.0  1.4  2.0 

$`01/02`
     min     mean      max 
2.000000 2.666667 3.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

We could try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Day = format(as.Date(Date, "%Y/%m/%d"), "%m/%d")) %>% 
   summarise(Min = min(Value), Max = max(Value), Mean = mean(Value))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Day     Min   Max  Mean
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 01/01     1     2  1.4 
2 01/02     2     3  2.67
```

---

If there are multiple columns, use `across`

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Day = format(as.Date(Date, "%Y/%m/%d"), "%m/%d")) %>% 
   summarise(across(Value, list(Min = min, Max = max, Mean = mean)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("1999/01/01", "1999/01/02", "2000/01/01", 
"2000/01/02", "2001/01/01", "2001/01/02"), Value = c(1.2, 2, 
1, 3, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```